# Scanf behavior when reading char

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have this code,

```
int firstNum;
int secondNum;
char operator;

NSLog(@"Please enter the first number");
scanf("%i", &firstNum);
NSLog(@"Please enter the operator"); //Line 3
scanf("%c", &operator);
NSLog(@"Please enter the second number");
scanf("%i", &secondNum);
```

When I run it and the system reaches Line 3, it doesn't wait for the user to type in a character value, instead it immediately executes the next line. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scanf("%c")` call does not skip whitespace (see [`scanf`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/scanf.3.html)).

> **c**    Matches a sequence of width count characters (default 1); the next
>              pointer must be a pointer to char, and there must be enough room
>              for all the characters (no terminating NUL is added).  *The usual
>              skip of leading white space is suppressed.*  To skip white space
>              first, use an explicit space in the format.

So it's reading whatever line ending char was left in the buffer after you read the first integer.

To explicitly skip whitespace, you could replace that with:

```
scanf(" %c", &operand);
```

Note that if the user enters `123 + 234` and hits enter at the first prompt, the two subsequent `scanf`s won't wait for any input but simply process `+` and `234`.

If that is a problem, read whole lines instead and use `sscanf`.